# my assembly language comparing characters give the wrong result

Tags: assembly, tasm

When comparing character my expected output is 'not equal' - but the output that tasm display is always 'equal'.

My program to compare the value in dl and bl if equal then display the equal and if not equal it display not equal

...but even equal or not equal the output is always equal i don't now where the problem is

```
 title compare.program
cstack segment para stack 'stack'
dw 200h
cstack ends

cdata segment para 'data'
msg1 db 'equal $'
msg2 db 'not equal $'
cdata ends

ccode segment para 'code'
Assume cs:ccode,ds:cdata,ss:cstack
main:
mov dl,'a'
mov bl, 'b'

compare:
cmp dl,bl
je correct
jmp wrong


correct:
mov ah,09
lea dx,msg1
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

wrong:
mov ah,09
lea dx,msg2
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

ccode ends
end main
```

Comment: Please single step the code with the input which calculates wrong, and work out where it diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `DS`:

```
...
main:

mov ax, cdata
mov ds, ax

mov dl,'a'
mov bl, 'b'
...
```

Comment: its working thanks. but i don't know what mov ax, cdata mov ds,ax is

Comment: @user3083254: Short: the computer has to know, where `msg1` and `msg2` are located. Therefore it looks at `DS` for a "segment address". Details in any tutorial or textbook!